# How to create an Automator service to convert images from one file type into another file type using the right-click contextual menu?

Tags: automator, file-conversion, shortcut-menu, contextual-menu

Is it possible to create an Automator service to convert one file type into another file type using the right click contextual menu (eg **JPEG, PDF, PNG, TIFF**) without the need to install a dedicated app to accomplish the desired file conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example Automator workflow to convert image files to a specific type:

[image: Automator Workflow]

When creating your workflow, don't forget to set it to a Service so that it can be accessed in the context menu.

The Copy Finder Items makes sure that the original files don't get replaces. You can change the save location to a variable if you wish, or just delete that action and let it replace the original file.

If you would like the option of which file type you would like, you can create multiple service workflows with different names (and different file formats for the Change Type of Images action).

Comment: How can I modify this action so that aphoto.heic will convert to aphoto.jpg keeping both the files in the same folder? I have added a copy file before change, but that make a aphoto copy.jpg and keep aphoto.heic.

Comment: @karim This looks like a new question? If so, please use Ask Question to ask this separately, including a link to this question if it helps provide context. If not, perhaps I'm not understanding what you're asking?