# Convert image type and save to relative folder with automator

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, file-conversion

I found a question and working answer here [How to create an Automator service to convert images from one file type into another file type using the right-click contextual menu?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94167/how-to-create-an-automator-service-to-convert-images-from-one-file-type-into-ano/) but it is saving the output file to desktop only. I can understand that this can be saved to relative path(like if source file is in directory /Desktop/Resources/myImage the output file in path /Desktop/Resources/myImage/Converted) with some actions in automator like set value for viable etc. But I am not familiar with that. How to use the **set value for variable** and **get value for variable**.

Comment: If no one does your work for you, feel free to edit in the code you have. It is far easier to point out a mistake than to teach someone to code from a problem statement of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to play with variables. When I configure the service as below, it makes a copy of the files (?!) when I use the `New Folder` action. Then it is a matter of converting the files in the new folder.

[image]

Comment: Very strange that the "New Folder" action copies the current folder contents to the new folder?? I didn't understand this script until I read your comment about the same...