# Convert image and save to same folder in Automator

Tags: finder, automator, file-conversion

I'm trying to figure out an Automator workflow (to make as a Service/Quick Action) to convert an images' file type - easy enough with the "Change Type Of Images" option. BUT, doing that alone replaces the original image - where i want to keep the original image.

Using the "Copy Finder Items" requires you to choose a location for the converted file, BUT, i want it to save to the same folder as the original, AND, i don't want to have to have a "choose folder" option come up every time.

I've read that it may not be possible without using "Variables" & "Applescript" - both of which i don't know. I would think that it should be more simple than that - that only if the "Copy Finder Items" had an option to use the same folder.

I [found another workflow](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205708/52080) where if you put the "New Folder" option in there, it will leave the original alone and copy it to the new folder and convert that one. i could do this if i have to, but would still rather the conversion to take place in the same folder as the orig.

any ideas?
thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following actions:

- Duplicate Finder Items
- Change Type of Images
- Rename Finder Items: Replace Text (" copy" with "")

With this sequence, the 'change type' occurs with the copy while ignoring the original. You end up with both files in the original folder.

NB To test as a workflow prior to rendering as a service, insert Get Specified Finder Items at the beginning and specify your test image(s).

Comment: AWESOME! this works great - THANK YOU!

Comment: My pleasure. I also find some of Automator's constraints to be quirky, obscure and frustrating. Amusingly, but on the separate issue of answer formatting — I had initially typed my reply as it now (bullets) but before saving, changed it to 'code' (as I generally avoid using bullets for things where sequence is important). I guess I should look for a style guide.

Comment: I have added the renaming of the finder object as another step. I search for " Copy" and replace it with "".

Comment: or even better, get rid of the first and last action, and just convert/replace the files, so you don't end up with tons of duplicates. All you really need is; "Change Type of Images".